# Spring Cloud RestTemplate get null object body (parse Json null)?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, resttemplate

while I use RestTemplate with String ResponseType,It run normal.

```
ResponseEntity<String> response = restTemplate.postForEntity(uri,
request, String.class);
```

Return Json String

```
{"code":0,"message":null,"data":"{\"companyId\":\"1\",\"tinyIdList\":[\"2\"],\"carId\":\"3\"}"}
```

While I use Java POJO to save response,Java Object's Attributes are all null

```
ResponseEntity<queryTinyListResponse> responseEntity = restTemplate.postForEntity(uri, request, queryTinyListResponse.class);
```

Result:

```
body:queryTinyListResponse{data=Data{tinyIdList=[], carId='null', companyId='null'}, code=0, msg='null'}
```

queryTinyListResponse.class:

```
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
public class queryTinyListResponse implements Serializable {
    public class Data{
        private String companyId;
        private List<String> tinyIdList=new ArrayList<String>();
        private String carId;
        //getter setter getCompanyId() etc..

    }
    public Data getData() {
        return data;
    }

    //getter setter
    private  Data data;
    private int code;
    private String msg;
}
```

Comment: Check if the response header from the server for the content type application/json?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found an answer to this question. I should use `static` inner class [here](http://%20https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24650167/fail-filling-object-from-json-with-resttemplate/51098728#51098728)

Found It !!. The solution is quite strange actually. The problem comes from the inner classes. The old structure was like this :

```
public class MetaData{
  ...
  public class Data {

     ....

     public class Item{
       ...
     }
   }
}
```

The inner classes have to be `static` because there is no way Jackson can instantiate directly an inner class.

```
public class MetaData{
  ...
  public static class Data {

     ....

   public static class Item{
       ...
     }
   }
}
```

Everything worked just fine. Hope that helped !

Answer (score 0):

you can use in your application.properties/yml this configuration: `spring.jackson.default-property-inclusion=non_null` and then I tried to reproduce a similar configuration and I found in your response string

```
{"code":0,"message":null,"data":"{\"companyId\":\"1\",\"tinyIdList\":[\"2\"],\"carId\":\"3\"}"}
```

a jeson syntax error it should be `{\"code\":0,\"message\":null,\"data\":{\"companyId\":\"1\",\"tinyIdList\":[\"2\"],\"carId\":\"3\"}}` otherwise the data field is saw as a string and not a Data object.

if you want try your self you can try this code:

```
package com.example.jacksondemo;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIgnoreProperties;
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.http.RequestEntity;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PostMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;
import org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

@SpringBootApplication
public class JacksonDemoApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(JacksonDemoApplication.class, args);
    }
}

@lombok.Data
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
class QueryTinyListResponse implements Serializable {

    //getter setter
    private  Data data;
    private int code;
    private String msg;
}

@lombok.Data
class Data implements Serializable {
    private String companyId;
    private List<String> tinyIdList=new ArrayList<String>();
    private String carId;
    //getter setter getCompanyId() etc..

}

@RestController
class QueryTinyListResponseController {

    @PostMapping
    public String query(){
        return "{\"code\":0,\"message\":null,\"data\":{\"companyId\":\"1\",\"tinyIdList\":[\"2\"],\"carId\":\"3\"}}";

    }
}


@RestController
class QueryTinyListResponseControllerClient {

    @GetMapping("/client")
    public QueryTinyListResponse query(){
        RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();

        return restTemplate.postForEntity("http://localhost:8080/", RequestEntity.EMPTY, QueryTinyListResponse.class).getBody();
    }
}
```

application.properties

```
spring.jackson.default-property-inclusion=non_null
```